# Questions on Asymptotic Dominance

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I'm trying to simplify the asymptotic dominance of an algorithm and I'm just looking to clarify whether or not `O(log(n))` is the same as `O(log(n^2))` since `log(n^2)` is just `2*log(n)` and is therefore in the form of `c*log(n)`.  Is this correct or is my logic wrong?  Also is it bad to include floor and ceiling notations when declaring order? For example `O(floor(log(n)))`?

Comment: For every choice of base `log(n) == 2*log(n)` from the definition of logarithm. Any presumed use of floor or ceiling is irrelevant during the use of Big-O and Big-Theta notation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `O(log n)` is the same as `O(log n^2)`

`O(floor(log n))` is the same as `O(log n)` too, just note that

```
c log n <= c (floor(log n) + 1) 
        < c (floor(log(n)) + floor(log(n))) 
        = 2c floor(log(n))
```

And also apparently

```
c floor(log(n)) <= c log n
```